# Decrypting a string using RSA

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, encryption, rsa

the scenario is as follows: I am asked to implement a decryption algorithm in Javascript to decrypt a string that was encoded using RSA with the following algorithm:

1. Convert the string to some list of integers (4 chars to 1 integer) we call this list u[].
2. Apply this operation for all elements in u[]: `e[i] = RSA((u[i]-e[i-1]) mod n), e[-1] = 0`
3. Then we get the encrypted list of integers e[].

A textual description of step 2:
We encrypt the first element, subtract the encrypted first element from the second element. Then we do  (modulo n) and then encrypt the result. And the process continues for the rest of the numbers.

Now the problem is the decryption part.
I have been stuck at this part for hours!

I worked with the equation, with the goal of making u[n] the subject:

```
e[i] = RSA((u[i]-e[i-1]) mod n) -- (1)
```

We know:

```
RSA(x) = x^e mod n -- (2) 
RSA'(x) = x^d mod n -- (3)
```

So, from (1) and (3)

```
RSA'(e[i]) = (u[i]-e[i-1]) mod n
RSA'(e[i]) + k*i + e[i-1] = u[i]
```

Then i am kind of stuck, because we do not know k.

So, i tried again:

```
RSA'(e[i]) = (u[i]-e[i-1]) mod n
(e[i])^d mod n = (u[i]-e[i-1]) mod n
```

That seems to go no where too...

Comment: Who tells people to implement such clearly broken crypto? ARGHHHH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second step doesn't make much sense, shouldn't it be:

```
e[i] = RSA((u[i]-e[i-1]) mod n), e[-1] = 0
```

That is, the modulus is independent of the index. It doesn't make much sense because to get `e[0]` you would have to calculate something modulo 0 (equally nonsensical as dividing by zero), and for `e[1]` you have to calculate something modulo 1 and the result of that is always 0.

Furthermore, if `n` is the RSA modulus, for the plain text you have `0 <= u[i] < n`. This means that the second step in reverse is just

```
u[i] = (RSA'(e[i]) + e[i-1]) mod n
```

Comment: Whoops typo that I didn't edit in time:
Hm, the actual message encrypted is u[i] - e[i-1] mod n. I don't see an obvious reason why u[i] is bounded by n... other than maybe the assumption that it's the bitwise concatenation of four alphabetical chars.

Comment: I think your assumption is valid just because you could prove that it's irreversible without that assumption (just take any string and replace `u[0]` with `u[0] + n`).

Comment: What is n? If n is the RSA modulus it's not unreasonable to assume that all arithmetic is modulo n.

Comment: Yes, I'm using your notation. `u[i]` was just defined as "4 chars to 1 integer". If he means bit concatenation I don't see why you would assume it's modulo n...

Comment: Oops, sorry! I mixed up my indexing! I fixed the question!

Comment: Hmmm... It works! But i dont quite get the unique modulo part! Could you point me to some reading materials so i can better understand it? Thanks! :D

Comment: What I mean is that, for a plain text block `u[i]` there can be `n` encryption results. If `u[i]` can take more than `n` values by the pigeon hole principle at least two of them are encrypted to the same cipher text, and it's impossible to know which of the two is the original: you can only find `u[i] mod n`.